# How can I show the hierarchy symbols when using “lsblk”

Tags: linux, lsblk

When I run `lsblk`, I get (example)

```
sda
|-sda1
| `-rhel-root
|-sda2
  `-rhel-home
```

On another server I get the proper characters displaying the hierarchy.

```
sda
└─sda1
| └─rhel-root
└─sda2
  └─rhel-home
```

How can I get this on the first server above? Do I need to yum install a certain rpm?
I tried setting `LC_ALL=C`, or `LC_ALL=en_US`. Neither fixed it.

Comment: Your locale should probably contain UTF-8, e.g. en_US.UTF-8, you must have a terminal app which can display such symbols and your terminal app font must contain them.

Comment: Setting LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 gives me strange characters. â”, â””€

Comment: lsblk -i doesn’t change anything. I’m still getting `-rhel-home

Comment: Which application are you using to connect to the servers? Putty? Make sure you have the same settings for both servers.

Comment: Yes I’m using the same application. For the server that is working, nothing is set for LC_ALL

Comment: Are servers running the same distro and release? Is `locale` output the same for both of them? You might have two different configurations in putty for them that's why you're getting different results.

Answer (score 0):

I had another problem with locale, and this fixed it for me.

Running either (as root):

```
localectl set-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Or:

```
echo "LANG=en_US.UTF-8" > /etc/default/locale (Ubuntu/Debian)
echo "LANG=en_US.UTF-8" > /etc/locale.conf (CentOS/RHEL)
```

Comment: That didn’t help. I’m still getting â”, â””€

Comment: Did you try changing the terminal font as suggested above?